# FreshMVVM - best way to open a page from a child ContentView that doesn't inherit from FreshBasePageModel

Tags: xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

The following code shows 2 examples of an OpenPage `Command`.  The one in `MainPageModel` works since it derives directly from `FreshBasePageModel`.  However, the second OpenPage call in the `ChildPageModel` won't work (or compile).  I don't want to pass the parent model all around.  So how, using FreshMVVM, do I open a new page from the `ChildPageModel` (and have the back button work, etc)?

```
public class MainPageModel : FreshBasePageModel
{
    public Command OpenPage
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() =>
            {
                CoreMethods.PushPageModel<NewPageModel>();
            });
        }
    }

    public ChildPageModel ChildPageModel { get; set; }
}

public class ChildPageModel 
{
    public Command OpenPage
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() =>
            {
                // ??????
                CoreMethods.PushPageModel<NewPageModel>();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will accomplish this...

```
var page = FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel<MainPageModel>();
var model = page.GetModel() as MainPageModel;
var navService = FreshMvvm.FreshIOC.Container.Resolve<IFreshNavigationService>();
await navService.PushPage(page, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also make the ChildPageModel inherit from FreshBasePageModel. All PageModels should inherit from FreshBasePageModel

Answer (score 0):

I make a simple example with three pages (MainPage, SecondPage, ThirdPage). You could download the source file of FreshMVVMDemo folder from HitHub.
https://github.com/WendyZang/Test.git

If you want to open a new page, you could add command in the child page.

```
#region Commands
    public Command GotoPageCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                await CoreMethods.PushPageModel<ThirdPageModel>(); //replace the ThirdPageModel with the page you want to open
            });
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

If you want to go back, add the command like below.

```
 #region Commands
    public Command GoBackSecondCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                //await CoreMethods.PopPageModel();  //go back to main page
                await CoreMethods.PushPageModel<SecondPageModel>(); //Go back to third page
            });
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your example has 3 pages all which inherit from FreshBasePageModel. I am actually asking how to navigate to a page from a child of the page model that doesn't inherit from FreshBasePageModel. And, that's a simple example above to highlight what I am trying to accomplish. I have a valid reason for structuring the code in this manner.

Comment: @JohnLivermore The FreshBasePageModel is the base class of FreshMVVM NuGet package. If you want to use FreshMVVM, you need to inherit FreshBasePageModel first.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand how to use FreshMVVM.  That's not my issue.  If you have a complex page and want to break it into discrete ContentViews (my situation), and have models that match those ContentViews and are properties off the main FreshBasePageModel (as above), then sometimes you need to navigate to a new page off those child models.  Extending those from FreshBasePageModel won't work as there is no context to set it up (you don't 'navigate' to those child views).  I just want to know how to resolve something that can invoke a new page and keep FreshMVVM in sync.

Comment: We could not do that, all the child page we want to navigate to with keeping FreshMVVM in async should all inherit this base Model.